# Pass variable from ChildFragment to an Activity Android

Tags: android

I have this guestbook app in android. The structure of the app is somewhat like this.
LoginActivity (using intent to put extra(password)) -> MainActivity (get Extra, FragmentManager) -> TabFragment -> (ChildFragment) Fragment1, Fragment2, SettingFragment and so on.

I have Edittext in SettingFragment to change the password that's gonna be used to login in LoginActivity. By using the getText I got the value of edittext and store it in variable.

The problem is,,,,the variable that I got from SettingFragment returning null in LoginActivity. Is there any way to get the variable ? Thanks in advance

Below is my LoginActivity code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
    admin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_admin);
    user = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btn_user);
    txtAdmin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_pin);

    admin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login();
        }
    });

    user.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("key", "user");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

public void login(){
        if (txtAdmin.getText().toString().equals(SettingFragment.getPin)) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("key", SettingFragment.getPin);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong PIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

SettingFragment

```
String setPin;
public static String getPin;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.setting_layout, container, false);
    setPin = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.pin);

    save = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.save);

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           getPin = setPin.getText().toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you want the password for the time you're using the app or you'll use it the next time you'll open the app??

Comment: I need the password by the time app is launched...it first launch LoginActivity

Comment: You need to save password in `sharedpreference`. so you can use it next time you run your app.

Comment: you can use sharePreference if you want it for short duration or use Sqlite db if you want to store and use it for a longer period of time

Answer (score 0):

u can add a method to LoginActivity called setPassword(String password), then call the method in settingsFragment's onclick listener of the save button。
or better: you can add an observer to SettingFragment.

Comment: I think its the other way,,,I make a method in SettingFragment to set the password and call it in oncreate LoginActivity...cuz I need the password from Edittext in SettingFragment to login

Comment: ur method is not valid, ur app's workflow is  first start LoginActivity, then start MainActivity, when the MainActivity become visible, LoginActivity will be at the bottom of the stack, MainActivity will be on top of the LoginActivity in the stack. After u input password in the SettingFragment  and go to LoginActivity again,  the MainActivity will be popped out first. This is the reason why u get null, u never know when the SettingFragment(int the MainActivity) class will be recycled.

Comment: It's a better solution to set password in the LoginActivity, when u input password int the settingfragment or save it in the db or sp